# Virtual ground in a non-inverting ideal op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image: Circuit in question]

Say the input to the non-inverting terminal to this op-amp is 5 V, what is the voltage at the inverting terminal? I always assumed that the non-inverting and inverting terminals have the same voltage at all times but this is not reflected in simulation.

What is the correct answer here?

I guess the main question to ask is: why don't the terminals have the same voltage in an op-amp?

Comment: Operational amplifier tries to equalize voltage at inverting and noninverting inputs (on input differential stage) if opamp have negative feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I always assumed that the non-inverting and inverting terminals have the same voltage at all times but this is not reflected in simulation.

At all times? Nope. This is true if and only if there's a negative feedback. Without feedback the op amp can't equalise its inputs.

If you want the inverting input to be equal to the non-inverting input then tie the bottom end of that 1k resistor to output instead of ground:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fo8LtF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

NOTE: Theoretically R1 can be anything but open (infinite resistance) as an op amp's inputs draw zero current. Shorting it will create an ideal buffer (a.k.a. follower).

Comment: I have no idea how I have never realized this until now. So if there isn't feedback, the voltage at the inverting terminal can be assumed to be 0 or very close to 0 when a voltage is applied to the non-inverting terminal?

Comment: The opamp does not directly control the voltage at the input terminals. The only thing it controls is the output terminal. So if there is no feedback, the input terminals will have exactly the voltages they look like they have. The op-amp without feedback has as much impact on the input terminals as a brick, or a ham sandwich. (I.e. none whatsoever.)

Comment: @codingliketheresnoyesterday it is close to 0 for the very reason that you connected it to ground via s resistor.

Comment: @codingliketheresnoyesterday `So if there isn't feedback, the voltage at the inverting terminal can be assumed to be 0 or very close to 0 ...` Theoretically 0, as it's terminated with a 1k resistor. Practically, since almost all of the op amps have their input bias current flow from pin to outside (i.e. not into the pin) that bias current can generate microvolts, nanovolts, or even millivolts across that 1k resistor (close to 0). `... when a voltage is applied to the non-inverting terminal?` regardless of the non-inv terminal voltage, we should say. Applying supply voltage only is enough.